# Does AngularFire2 support update of user credentials?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 (2.0.0-beta.2) incombination with angular2 (2.0.0-rc.4).  Using Angularfire I can programatically create a user (email/password) with

```
angularFire.auth.createUser({email : this.email, password; this.password})
```

That part works as expected. Subsequently, I would like to update either the email address or password. I've examined the AngularFire source and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to do this. Am I correct in this assessment? And if I'm correct, should I expect to see a mechanism in upcoming releases or should I just use the native Firebase mechanisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try an answer my own question. I think that the AngularFire2 public API's are missing some functionality related to firebase authentication. For example I don't think the present version of AngularFire (2.0.0-beta2) has the ability to update the email address or password, or send the password reset email. I think the solution to this present shortcoming is to get the native firebase objet and just use the native firebase methods to resolve. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to get access to the native FireBase object using AngularFire2.  I've posted [this](http://I'm%20using%20AngularFire2%20(2.0.0-beta.2)%20i) question to see if anyone can help me do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to use `$firebaseAuth()`. Just inject it in your controller and go with

```
$firebaseAuth().$updateEmail("email@email.com");
$firebaseAuth().$updatePassword("newpass123");
```

Comment: This doesn't work with angular2. In angular 2 (as of 2.0.0-rc.4) the methods on the angularfire.auth are various overloaded versions of login, logout, getAuth() and createUser(). I think the solution you have suggested works in previous versions of FB but not 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer will be helpful, **Password** can be changed by **firebase-admin** using cloud function you will just have to pass **email** and **new password** from the client-side(Angular, ionic, ...)

**Cloud function:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const resetUserPassword = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {

return cors( req, res, async () => {
    const email = req.body.data.email;
    const password = req.body.data.password;

    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
    .then((getUserRecord) => {
      admin.auth().updateUser(getUserRecord.uid, {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        res.send({
          status: 200,
          data: userRecord
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        res.send({
          status: 500,
          data: error
        })
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
  })
});
```

**Client side code(IONIC):**

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
export class AuthService {
constructor(
 private functions: AngularFireFunctions
) {}
  resetUserPassword() {
    const userNewCredential = {email: 'user-email', password: 'your-new-password'};
    this.functions.httpsCallable('resetUserPassword') 
    (userNewCredential).toPromise().then((updatedUser) => {
      console.log(updatedUser);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
 }
```